# Different ways of recursive data fetching with Relay? Which one is better and other questions

Tags: recursion, reactjs, relay

Recently I've made a component for recursive classifier with `Relay`.
I made it with two ways. One of which did not work and the second worked.
From the end-user side they both look the same with the same functionality.
In short the task is pretty much a general recursive data fetching with fetching
on next level expand.

The first way:

Fetch data after setting the relay variable `expand`. It is made via the
recursive fragment composition. The main part is this:

```
const CategoryItemContainer = Relay.createContainer(CategoryItem, {
  initialVariables: {
    expanded: false,
  },

  fragments: {
    category: (variables) => Relay.QL`
        fragment on Category {
            id
            name
            hasChildren

            ${CategoryItemSubcategoryListContainer.getFragment('categories').if(variables.expanded)}
        }
    `,
  },
});

const CategoryItemSubcategoryListContainer = Relay.createContainer(CategoryItemSubCategoryList, {
  fragments: {
    categories: () => Relay.QL`
        fragment on Category {
            categories(first: 10000) {
                edges {
                    node {
                        ${CategoryItemContainer.getFragment('category')}
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    `,
  },
});
```

This way it is supposed that the `Relay.RootContainer` is called just once. It
did not work for me but I know that others implemented it and everything's OK (it's
a subject for another post).

The second way:

The second way worked for me easy. I don't use `Relay` variables but I call
`Relay.Renderer` for the next level of recursion depending on the UI component's
state. Like this:

```
{this.state.hasOwnProperty(category.id) ? // <- changing the state triggers the recursion
  <Relay.Renderer
  Container={CategoryItemSubCategoryListContainer}
  queryConfig={new CategoryRoute({ id: category.id })}
  environment={Relay.Store}
  render={({ done, error, props, retry, stale }) => {  
    if (error) {
      return 'Error';
    } else if (props) {
      return <CategoryItemSubCategoryListContainer {...props}
                                                   maxLevel={maxLevel}
                                                   currentLevel={currentLevel + 1}
                                                   activeCats={this.props.activeCats}
                                                   elementSelectedCallback={elementSelectedCallback}/>;
    }

    return (
      <ul className="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
        <li>
          <div className="list-group-item"><p className="text-center"><img src="img/ajax-loader.gif"/></p></div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    );
  }}
  /> : ''}
```

This works just as I expected to. Moreover I have a nice loader icon for the
next level everytime.

So, having this I've got three questions:

**The first**

Is any of these methods the preferrable one? Maybe there are drawbacks
somewhere that I don't know? I'd like to understand this since I'm introducing
`Relay` to my company and I'm willing to replace all the legacy frontend with
`React` and `Relay`.

**The second**

At some point in time a user will pick a category from this recursive
classifier and I will have to get the full path of data that led to the current
level.
I mean if a user picks a category at the level 3 of the hierarchy, I must give
back these data:

```
[root cat id, root cat name],
[level 1 cat id, level 1 cat name],
[level 2 cat id, level 2 cat name]
```

So when I catch the event of picking inside the component at the level 2 how can
I get the full path from the root category from `Relay`? I thought that I can
use some `Relay` API to get them from store? Or do I have to implement this
store myself?

**The third**

As I said in the second way of implementation there's a nice feature that I
get the loading spinner every time the `Relay.Renderer` is called. How can this
be done in the first way? I mean in the first way data fetching is hidden inside
fragment composition and and is triggered by the `setVariables`. Should I
trigger the spinner right before the `setVariables` method and then turn it off
in the `onReadyStateChange` of the only `Relay.RootContainer`? But then it seems
like I have to make a global store of spinners' state for rendered containers..
I'm confused here..